# Firing order for multiple $(document).ready(function(){... in ASP.NET MVC page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a master page Default.master which contains a script tag to load Master.js.

```
  <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/Shared/Master.js") %>" 
                  type="text/javascript">     
</script>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" />
```

Then I have a content page Upload.aspx based upon Default.master which contains a script tag to load Upload.js in the header content area.

```
<asp:Content ID="contentHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
  <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/Store/Upload.js") %>" 
     type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

BOTH Master.js and Upload.js contain a $(document).ready(function(){...

Here is the rendered head element on the page

```
<head>
<link href="/Content/Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/jQuery/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/Plugins/MBTooltip/MBTooltip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Plugins/Json/jquery.json-1.3.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Plugins/Dropshadow/jquery.dropshadow-1.6.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Plugins/Timers/jquery.timers-1.1.2.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Plugins/MBTooltip/mbTooltip.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Shared/jquery.utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Shared/Master.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/Content/Store.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/Scripts/Store/Upload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

And the .read() from Master.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //No selected patient to start with.
  selectedPatient = null;
  //ToDo: Load last active patient?
  activePatient = null;

  //Get/display active patient
  GetActivePatient();

  //Attach events
  $("#patientSelectDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Patient Selection',
    resizable: false,
    width: 660,
    height: 475
  });

  $('#btnPatientSearch').click(function() {
    GetPatientList();
    $("#txtPatientSearch").val("");
    $("#txtPatientSearch").focus();
  });

  $('#txtPatientSearch').keypress(function(e) {
    //ENTER
    if (e.which == 13) {
      GetPatientList();
      $("#txtPatientSearch").val("");
      $("#txtPatientSearch").focus();
    }
  });

  $("#patientSearchList").click(function() {
    GetSelectedPatient();
  });

  $('#btnActivatePatient').click(function() {
    ActivatePatient();
  });

  $('#btnNewPatient').click(function() {
    NewPatient();
  });

  $('#btnEditPatient').click(function() {
    EditPatient();
  });

  $('#btnSavePatient').click(function() {
    SavePatient(false);
  });

  $('#btnSaveActivatePatient').click(function() {
    SaveActivatePatient();
  });

  $('#btnCancelPatient').click(function() {
    CancelPatient();
  });

  //Hide patient edit initially
  $('#patientEdit').hide();

  /*3rd party setups*/

  //MBTooltip setup
  $("[title]").mbTooltip({
    opacity: .90, //opacity
    wait: 500, //before show
    ancor: "mouse", //"parent"
    cssClass: "default", // default = default
    timePerWord: 70, //time to show in milliseconds per word
    hasArrow: false,
    color: "white",
    imgPath: "images/",
    shadowColor: "black",
    fade: 500
  });

});
```

And from Upload.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if (!IsPatientActive()) {
    $("#fileUpload").attr("disabled", "true");
    $("#btnUpload").attr("disabled", "true");
    $("#noActivePatient").removeAttr("display");
  }
  else {
    $("#noActivePatient").attr("display", "none");
  }
});
```

I expected the $(document).ready(function(){... in Master.js to fire first since that script is loaded first, followed by the one in Upload.js. However, the Upload.js is firing first. I have verified the firing order by putting breakpoints w/ both VS2008 and Firebug.

Is there a way to control the order of firing?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready) do say, "The functions are then executed in the order they were added."  Are you sure Master.js is first in the rendered page?  Did you look in Firebug on DOM Inspector?

Comment: Yes, just verified again (see below from Firebug)

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Shared/Master.js">
</script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Store.css">
</link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Store/Upload.js">

Comment: can u paste the script files. I know for sure that they fire in order parsed

Comment: I edited the Question to include the ready() code and <head> tag in the rendered page. The JS files are pretty large.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if this would make any difference but the way you included your Master.js file you have an unecessary  tag at the beginning.

just change it to be similar to how you included your Upload.js file

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/Shared/Master.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Another hard-to-identify bug found! Somehow the lack of good debugging tool for js and html is very annoying and many time you are finding the reason in logic but end up the problem came from your mis-spelling!

Comment: Just a copy/paste error. The script tags are correct in the actual page.

Answer (score 0):

It will not make any difference in what order they are executed. Because the DOM tree and variables are all setup by then unless you are setting up somethings in upload.js itself.

You may put the init code in the master.js and call init functions of upload.js from there based on some conditional variable which can be set on the pages where you are using the later (upload.js).

Also it reminds me about [K. Scoot Allen's](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2005/09/10/2179.aspx) rant about master page anti pattern.

Comment: It would be problematic to call something in Upload.js from Master.js because Upload is really a "child" of Master. Having code in master to call stuff on child pages would be cumbersome as there are quite a few pages on the site.

I want to be able to all functions in Master from child pages so they can be shared/reused across all pages.

Comment: Just a followup. Everything in the master page and associated JS file deal w/ the elements on the master page, specifically the header area. What I need to do from the child page init is determine the status of information in the header that is carried from page to page.